# Android - How do I attach the private key used by ant release for signing to GNOME Keyring?

Tags: android, keystore, gnome-keyring-daemon

Apparently, Java uses a different format for signing than gnome-keyring/GPG. Gnome Keyring uses [PKCS #11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS11), while Java uses [PKCS #12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS12). I don't like the idea of having .keystore files floating around, so I would like to use Gnome Keyring / Seahorse for easy central management of all my keys. This is especially important since Android developers are expected to keep their keys safe for 25+ years!

How do I convert/attach the Java keystore to my keyring, such that when running `ant release` I can use GNOME Keyring to enter the password?